# redis servicestack client List.Remove(item) does not work

Tags: c#, servicestack.redis

I'm developing a "Task Control System" that will allow its users to enter task description information including when to execute the task and what environment (OS, browser, etc.) the task requires.

The 'controller' saves the description information and schedules the task.  When the scheduled time arrives, the scheduler retrieves the task information and 'queues' the task for a remote machine that matches the required environment.

My first cut at this used a relational database to persist the task descriptions and enough history information to track problems (about 2 weeks worth).  But this is not a 'big data' problem and the relationships are simple and I need better performance.

So I'm looking for something that offers more performance.
I'm trying to use redis for this, but I'm having some problems.  I'm using ServiceStack.Redis version 3.9.71.0 for the client and Redis 2.8.4 is the server.

This sample code is taken from Dan Swain's tutorial.  It's updated to work with ServiceStack.Redis client v 3.9.71.0.  Much of it works, but 'currentShippers.Remove(lameShipper);' does NOT work.
Can anyone see why that might be?

Thanks

```
   public void ShippersUseCase()
    {
        using (var redisClient = new RedisClient("localhost"))
        {
            //Create a 'strongly-typed' API that makes all Redis Value operations to apply against Shippers
            var redis = redisClient.As<Shipper>();

            //Redis lists implement IList<T> while Redis sets implement ICollection<T>
            var currentShippers = redis.Lists["urn:shippers:current"];
            var prospectiveShippers = redis.Lists["urn:shippers:prospective"];

            currentShippers.Add(
                new Shipper
                    {
                        Id = redis.GetNextSequence(),
                        CompanyName = "Trains R Us",
                        DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        ShipperType = ShipperType.Trains,
                        UniqueRef = Guid.NewGuid()
                    });

            currentShippers.Add(
                new Shipper
                    {
                        Id = redis.GetNextSequence(),
                        CompanyName = "Planes R Us",
                        DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        ShipperType = ShipperType.Planes,
                        UniqueRef = Guid.NewGuid()
                    });

            var lameShipper = new Shipper
                                  {
                                      Id = redis.GetNextSequence(),
                                      CompanyName = "We do everything!",
                                      DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow,
                                      ShipperType = ShipperType.All,
                                      UniqueRef = Guid.NewGuid()
                                  };

            currentShippers.Add(lameShipper);

            Dump("ADDED 3 SHIPPERS:", currentShippers);

            currentShippers.Remove(lameShipper);

            .
            .
            .

        }
    }
```

Fixed the problem by adding these overrides to the 'Shipper' class:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var input = obj as Shipper;
        return input != null && Equals(input);
    }

    public bool Equals(Shipper other)
    {
        return other != null && (Id.Equals(other.Id));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)Id;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This working example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows how to implement List<>.Contains, List<>.Find, and List<>.Remove.  Once applied to the 'Shipper' class the problem was solved!